# When we are taking moments about a uniform beam why dont we include support forces of the weights when taking moments?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Why don't we include the support forces when taking moments in the diagram below?[image]

Comment: Because it's an idealized setup, the hinge is assumed to be friction free and immovable.

We also do not consider the mass of the beam, it's properties (could have been made out of rubber..), air resistance, how are the forces applied? I could go on for ever. It also does not look like a section about beams...

Comment: You could imagine the beam pressing down with $W_1+W_2$ and the pivot exerting an equal and opposed counter force if that helps.

Comment: So the support force acts directly above the  beam centre of mass? Hence when we are taking centre of mass as pivot why do we ignore the forces at the pivot ?

Comment: Yes, because the distance from the pivot is zero so the moment is zero.

Comment: Thank you very.

Comment: So the support forces exerted by each weight is equivalent to one support force through centre of mass . How do u prove so? @JohnRennie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the only support force is vertical reaction force at the pivot (assumed frictionless). When taking the moments about the pivot for equilibrium, the support force contributes no moment.

On the other hand, if we take the moments about the point where W1 (or W2) is connected, the pivot reaction would contribute a counter clockwise (or clockwise) moment about W1 (or W2)..

But it doesn't matter where on the beam you take the moments. The end result will be the same. For equilibrium the sum of the moments has to be zero taken at any location on the beam.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

The pivot exerts a force of $(W_1 + W_2)$ but the pivot distance is zero. The moment of the pivot point is $0(W_1+W_2)=0$. A good choice of where the moments are taken around makes the algebra easier.

Let's make it harder and see we get to the same answer. Take moments counterclockwise around $W_1$ of $(W_1+W_2)d_1$ equal to the clockwise moment of $W_2(d_1 +d_2)$:

$(W_1+W_2)d_1=W_2(d_1 +d_2)$

$(W_1d_1+W_2d_1=W_2d_1 +W_2d_2)$

Now subtract $W_2d_1$ from both sides and we are back to the books equation.